# Why my openGL program cann't resolved GLEW symbols on Windows 10 + VS 2015?

Tags: opengl, glew

I'm building glfw+glew OpenGL development environment based on Windows 10 + Vistual studio Community 2015, then I try to compile my codes on it, but it doesn't work and always get some link error as below:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __glewCompileShader
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __glewCreateShader
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __glewGetShaderiv
...
```

I followed [GLEW offical guide](http://glew.sourceforge.net/install.html), and I checked my project configuration many times:

```
copy glew-1.13.0/bin/Release/Win32/glew32.dll to %SystemRoot%/system32
copy glew-1.13.0/lib/Release/Win32/glew32.lib to \Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib
copy glew-1.13.0/include/GL/glew.h to \Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include/GL
copy glew-1.13.0/include/GL/wglew.h to \Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include/GL
```

Is this GLEW library doesn't support Window 10? Or how I make it work?

Comment: Never copy files from third-party projects into the Visual Studio install directories.  The compiler and linker search paths are configurable for a reason.  (Why oh why does GLEW official guidance get this so wrong?)

Comment: do you know which version of glew I should choose to use on Win10? Win32 or x64? thank you.

Comment: Win10 runs 32-bit programs just fine, so both versions of GLEW work on it.  You need the bitness of your library to match the bitness of the application you're building with it.